# C# ClassA has many ClassB, how to access ClassA instance method from ClassB instance

Tags: c#, .net, class, parent-child, has-many

My C# program needs to receive xml data and store it in sql database. I have Batches which has many Instructions. I implement the classes thusly:

```
class Batch
{
    public string batchUID { get; set; }
    public Instruction[] instructionArray { get; set; }
}

class Instruction
{
    public string instructionUID { get; set; }
}
```

My program runs like this

```
Batch myBatch = new Batch();
myBatch.instructionArray = new Instruction[3];
myBatch.instructionArray[0] = new Instruction();
SomeFunc(myBatch.instructionArray[0]);

public void SomeFunc(Instruction instruction)
{
    // How do I do the following?
    console.write( instruction.OWNER.batchUID )
}
```

I have tried to search for this extensively but every result is related to inheritance, inner/outer classes, etc. I would like to avoid creating a batchUID method inside class Instruction if possible.

Comment: `new Instruction[3]` just sizes the array, all values will be `null`, there are no `Instruction` instances in there. You have to create them, and the good moment there is that you pass the parent as a parameter to the constructor of `Instruction`.

Comment: You have to somehow set your instructions. `myBatch.instructionArray[2] = new Instruction { instructionUid = "foo" };`

Comment: whether i instantiate myBatch.instructionArray[n] or not makes no difference to my question...

Comment: @p4ndepravity The code sample you provided however has a serious bug and will just cause a `NullReferenceException`. So I had to point it out before you run into trouble there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an instance of `Batch` to the constructor of `Instruction`, and then store a reference to that `Batch` that you can expose with a property. (This was already shown in another answer - I'm repeating it because it provides context to what I'm going to add next.)

```
class Instruction
{
    public Instruction(Batch parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Batch Parent { get; private set; }
    public string InstructionUID { get; set; } 
}
```

Now `Instruction` has a `Parent` property that returns a `Batch`.

But there's a gap. If you call

```
var parent = batch.Instruction[0].Parent
```

is `parent == batch`? It looks like that's the intent. The `Instruction` contains a reference to the `Batch` that contains it.

But nothing is enforcing that. For example, I could do this:

```
someBatch.Instruction[0] = someOtherBatch.Instruction[1];
```

Now `someBatch` contains an array of `Instruction`, but at least one of them actually has `someOtherBatch` as its parent.

Maybe that possibility is no big deal, but I think that if `Parent` is meant to refer to the `Batch` containing the `Instruction` but it might not, then you haven't actually accomplished what you're aiming for.

I'd recommend creating a separate class that contains both a `Batch` and an `Instruction`. (Perhaps `ParentInstructionRelation`?)

```
public class ParentInstructionRelation
{
    Batch Parent {get;private set;}
    Instruction Instruction {get;private set;}

    public ParentInstructionRelation(Batch parent, Instruction instruction)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Instruction = instruction;
    }
}
```

That way `Instruction` doesn't need a reference to its parent. It probably shouldn't have a reference to its parent. What if the same `Instruction` is in two different instances of `Batch`? Which one is the parent?

But if `Batch` needs to expose an `Instruction` *and* a reference to itself, then it can do that by returning a `ParentInstructionRelation`. Or a class that reads the `Instruction` from `Batch` can create that relationship.

```
var instructions = batch.InstructionArray
    .Select(instruction => new ParentInstructionRelation(batch, instruction));
```

Comment: this was the closest to what I was looking for and also didn't bother explaining that i need to instantiate the variable. thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an issue:

```
myBatch.instructionArray = new Instruction[3];
```

That will just create an array with 3 `null` values, not 3 instances of `Instruction`. This is because a `class` is a reference type and it will not be instantiated automatically here (`struct`s however are, since they are value types and get all their values initialized in a default constructor which is then called). You still have to create those instructions before passing them to your method as you'd effectively just be passing `null`.

Then, when creating an instance of `Instruction`, just pass the parent as a parameter, and remember it in the class, like this:

```
class Instruction
{
    public Instruction(Batch parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Batch Parent { get; private set; }
    public string InstructionUID { get; set; } // Please start properties with an uppercase letter
}
```

This way, you can access the `Batch` instance to which the `Instruction` instance belongs later on.

```
Batch myBatch = new Batch();
myBatch.InstructionArray = new Instruction[3];
// TODO: Create the instances here, the array is just null null null now!
myBatch.InstructionArray[0] = new Instance(myBatch); // example
SomeFunc(myBatch.InstructionArray[0]);

public void SomeFunc(Instruction instruction)
{
    Console.Write(instruction.Parent.BatchUID)
}
```

If this is good design is another question, the `Instruction` might have the `SomeFunc` stuff inside itself, but I'm not sure what the project should achieve eventually.